# Django: Many-to-Many-query

Tags: django

```
class Image(models.Model):
  upload = models.FileField(upload_to='homepage/pic_folder/')
class Article(models.Model):
  images = models.ManyToManyField(Image)
```

These are my models of articles having several pictures. How can I do a Many-to-Many-query within my views.py, so that I can use it later in html?

Comment: What is the result you want to get? Why don't you use a FK instead of M2M?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like:

```
article = Article.objects.get(id=article-id)
article_images = article.images.all()
render(request, 'sampletemplate.html', {'images':article_images})
```

Comment: was not quite what I was looking for as one page has several articles with multiple pictures.

Comment: @TL84 oh ok. I thought you were trying to display images of a particular article, anyway your answer is correct for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Simply do that in the template *.html

```
{% for i in var %}
{% for img in i.images.all %}{{ img }}, {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```